# Magento custom modules reports not displaying it's admin view?

Tags: php, magento

Title says it, I created a small reports module to just display some very basic things, but my admin view is NOT displaying. I end up receiving a 404 not found with the URL of `/index.php/modulename/adminhtml_modulename/index/key/{the key}/`

Here's the tree of my module:

```
app
├── code
│   └── local
│       └── Company
│           └── ModuleName
│               ├── Block
│               │   ├── ModuleName.php
│               │   └── adminhtml
│               │       ├── ModuleName
│               │       │   └── Grid.php
│               │       └── ModuleName.php
│               ├── Helper
│               │   └── Data.php
│               ├── Model
│               │   └── ModuleName.php
│               ├── controllers
│               │   └── Adminhtml
│               │       └── ModuleNameController.php
│               └── etc
│                   └── config.xml
├── design
│   └── adminhtml
│       └── default
│           └── default
│               └── layout
│                   └── modulename.xml
└── etc
    └── modules
        └── Company_ModuleName.xml
```

And here are the file(s):

```
app/code/local/Company/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/ModuleName/Grid.php

<?php
Class Company_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_ModuleName_Grid Extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setId('modulenameGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setSubReportSize(false);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        parent::_prepareCollection();

        $this->getCollection()->initReport('modulename/modulename'); //indicator for model used to get data.

            return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('ordered_qty', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Quantity Ordered'),
            'align'     =>'right',
            'index'     =>'ordered_qty',
            'type'      =>'number'
            'total'     =>'sum',    //indicator that this field must be totalized at the end.
        ));
        $this->addColumn('item_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Item ID'),
            'align'  => 'right',
            'index'  => 'item_id',
            'type'   => 'number',
            'total'  => 'sum',
        ));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv',  Mage::helper('modulename')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml',  Mage::helper('modulename')->__('XML'));

            return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getReport($from, $to)
    {
        if (empty($from)) $from = $this->getFilter('report_from');
        if (empty($to))   $to   = $this->getFilter('report_to');

        $totalObj = Mage::getModel('reports/totals');
        $totals = $totalObj->countTotals($this, $from, $to);

        $this->setTotals($totals);
        $this->addGrandTotals($totals);

            return $this->getCollection()->getReport($from, $to);
    }
}



app/code/local/Company/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/ModuleName.php

<?php
Class Company_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_ModuleName Extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_modulename';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'modulename';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('modulename')->__(' Module Name Report');

            parent::__construct();

        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}



app/code/local/Company/ModuleName/Block/ModuleName.php

<?php
Class Company_ModuleName_Block_ModuleName Extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getModuleName()
    {
        if (!  $this->hasData('modulename')) $this->setData('modulename', Mage::registry('modulename'));

            return $this->getData('modulename');
    }
}



app/code/local/Company/ModuleName/controllers/Adminhtml/ModuleNameController.php

<?php
Class Company_ModuleName_Adminhtml_ModuleNameController Extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

            return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_initAction()->renderLayout();
    }

    public function exportCsvAction()
    {
        $this->_sendUploadResponse('modulename.csv', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('modulename/adminhtml_modulename_grid')->getCsv());

            return $this;
    }

    public function exportXmlAction()
    {
        $this->_sendUploadResponse('modulename.xml', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('modulename/adminhtml_modulename_grid')->getXml());

            return $this;
    }

    protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream') {
        $response = $this->getResponse();

        $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', '');
        $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
        $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
        $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
        $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
        $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
        $response->setBody($content);
        $response->sendResponse();

            exit;
    }
}



app/code/local/Company/ModuleName/etc/config.xml

<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
/**
 * @category   Company
 * @package    Company_ModuleName
 * @author     Jd Daniel
 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_ModuleName>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_ModuleName>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <modulename>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_ModuleName</module>
                    <frontName>modulename</frontName>
                </args>
            </modulename>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <report>
                <children>
                    <customers>
                        <children>
                            <modulename translate='title' module='modulename'>
                                <title> Module Name Report</title>
                                <action>modulename/adminhtml_modulename</action>
                            </modulename>
                        </children>
                    </customers>
                </children>
            </report>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <report>
                            <children>
                                <customers>
                                    <children>
                                        <modulename translate='title' module='modulename'>
                                            <title> Module Name Report</title>
                                            <action>modulename/adminhtml_modulename</action>
                                        </modulename>
                                    </children>
                                </customers>
                            </children>
                        </report>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <modulename>
                    <file>modulename.xml</file>
                </modulename>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <modulename>
                <class>Company_ModuleName_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>modulename</resourceModel>
            </modulename>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <modulename_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_ModuleName</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </modulename_setup>
            <modulename_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </modulename_write>
            <modulename_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </modulename_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <modulename>
                <class>Company_ModuleName_Block</class>
            </modulename>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <modulename>
                <class>Company_ModuleName_Helper</class>
            </modulename>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>



app/code/local/Company/ModuleName/Helper/Data.php

<?php
Class Company_ModuleName_Helper_Data Extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    // ....
}



app/code/local/Company/ModuleName/Model/ModuleName.php

<?php
Class Company_ModuleName_Model_ModuleName Extends Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setResourceModel('sales/order_item');
        $this->_init('sales/order_item','item_id');
   }

    public function setDateRange($from, $to) 
    {
        $this->_reset();
        $this->getSelect()
             ->joinInner(array(
                 'i' => $this->getTable('sales/order_item')),
                 'i.order_id = main_table.entity_id'
                 )
             ->where('i.parent_item_id is null')
             ->where("i.created_at BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}")
             ->where('main_table.state = \'complete\'')
             ->columns(array('ordered_qty' => 'count(distinct main_table.entity_id)'));

        // uncomment next line to get the query log:
        // Mage::log('SQL: '.$this->getSelect()->__toString());

            return $this;
    }

    public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}



app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/modulename.xml

<?xml version='1.0'?>
<layout version='0.1.0'>
    <modulename_adminhtml_modulename_index>
        <reference name='content'>
            <block type='modulename/adminhtml_modulename' name='modulename' />
        </reference>
    </modulename_adminhtml_modulename_index>
</layout>



app/etc/modules/Company_ModuleName.xml

<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_ModuleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_ModuleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you have an error in `config.xml` or `modulename.xml`
by you example it should be in `config.xml`:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <modulename>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Company_ModuleName</module>
                <frontName>modulename</frontName>
            </args>
        </modulename>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

but you also have `/index.php/modulename/adminhtml_modulename/index/key/{the key}/` and that means, the name of you controller is `modulename` as well ? If the name of your controller is for example TestController.php, then url should be: `/index.php/modulename/adminhtml_test/index/key/{the key}/`. if so, then mistake might be in `modulename.xml`

Comment: Close enough to get me there, the config needed the `<company_modulename>` and the Controller needed to be named `ModulenameController` no `ModuleNameController` Accepted, and plus 1